# How can i call jQuery-plugin function from aspx page by creating object?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, jquery-plugins

I have created a jQuery plugin and I can able to use that in `document.ready` function and javascript functions also (in pure HTML page).

Now I want to call that functions in ajax call success function in my .aspx. But it is not working even in javascript function in the .aspx page.

I have provided the code which I have used please help me

### My Plugin code

```
    $.fn.pluginName = function(options) {
        var defaults = {
            color: "white",
            BackgroundColor: "#556b2f"
        };
        if (this.length > 1) {
            this.each(function() { $(this).pluginName(options) });
            return this;
        }
        // public methods 
        this.initialize = function() {
            // do something ...
            return this;
        };
        this.myPublicMethod = function() {
            // do something ...
            alert('Hi!! Public Method Called');
        };
        return this.initialize();
    }
})(jQuery);
```

--------------------------My Plugin code End------------------------------

### My Html Code :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <a onclick="clickget();">Click To Call</a>
<div id='sel'></div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="sampleplugin.js"></script>
    <script>
      function clickget() {
        debugger;
        var dd= $('#sel').pluginName();
        dd.myPublicMethod();
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

---------------------------------My Html Code End-----------------------------

### in my .aspx I'm calling like this

```js
function getassignements() {

       var person = $("#sel").pluginName();
       person.myPublicMethod ("#sel");
 }
```

Comment: Where is you ajax code? By the looks of it you're trying to execute jQuery on your `.aspx` file, which is server side. By the time you call your javascript is possible that jQuery or document ready isn't even ready yet. You should use a proper ajax request and then execute your javascript when the request is completed.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply ..
I want to call ajax in my getassignements() function  and my function looks like below 

function getassignements() {
  $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "data.aspx/getdata",
                data: '',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (response) {
                    var person = $("#sel").pluginName();
      person.myPublicMethod ("#sel");
                }
            });
       
 }